# Extract word before the 1st occurrence of a special string

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array that contains elements like

```
@array=("link_dm &&& drv_ena&&&1",
        "txp_n_los|rx_n_lost",
        "eof &&& 2 &&& length =!!!drv!!!0");
```

I want to get all the characters before the first "&&&", and if the element doesn't have a "&&&", then I need to extract the entire element.

This is what I want to extract:

> likn_dm
>   txp_n_los|rx_n_lost
>   eof

I used

```
    foreach my $row (@array){
      if($row =~ /^(.*)\&{3}/){
        push @firstelements,$1;
      }
    }
```

But I'm getting

> link_dm &&& drv_ena
>   txp_n_los|rx_n_lost
>   eof &&& 2

Can somebody please suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps just `split`ting would be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (
    "link_dm &&& drv_ena&&&1",
    "txp_n_los|rx_n_lost",
    "eof &&& 2 &&& length =!!!drv!!!0"
);


foreach my $row (@array){
    my ($chars) = split /\&{3}/, $row, 2;
    print $chars, "\n"
}
```

Output:

```
link_dm 
txp_n_los|rx_n_lost
eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
@firstelements = map { m/^(.*?) *&&&/ ? $1 : $_ } @array;
```

Or, if you prefer `foreach` over `map` and `if` over `?:`:

```
foreach my $row (@array){
  if($row =~ /^(.*)\&{3}/) {
    push @firstelements, $1;
  } else {
    push @firstelements, $row;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (@array) {
    print "$1\n" if /([^ ]*)(?: *[&]{3}.*)?$/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using regular expressions, use the minimum spanning pattern: `.*?`. See `perldoc perlre` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short   );
use English   qw( -no_match_vars );  # Avoids regex performance penalty

use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

# conditional compile DEBUGging statements
# See http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2013/07/a-look-at-conditional-compiling-of.html
use constant DEBUG => $ENV{DEBUG};

# --------------------------------------

my @array = (
    "link_dm &&& drv_ena&&&1",
    "txp_n_los|rx_n_lost",
    "eof &&& 2 &&& length =!!!drv!!!0",
);

my @first_elements = ();
for my $line ( @array ){

  # check for '&&&'
  if( my ( $first_element ) = $line =~ m{ \A (.*?) \s* \&{3} }msx ){
    push @first_elements, $first_element;
  }else{
    push @first_elements, $line;
  }
}
print Dumper \@first_elements;
```